# Is there something wrong with this assembly code?

Tags: assembly, runtime-error, tasm, dosbox

This code is assemble using Turbo Assembler but when I try running it in DOSBox , it freezes and DOSBox dies. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
TITLE SAMPLE PROGRAM
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA
.CODE
MYCODE PROC
    MOV AX,04
    MOV BX,0212
    CMP AX, BX
    JG action1
    JLE action2
action1:
    ADD AL, 30
    JMP exit
action2:
    ADD BL, 20
    JMP exit
exit:
    MOV AX, 4CH
    INT 21H
MYCODE ENDP
END MYCODE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Exit to DOS](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah4c) is done by setting `AH` to `4CH` and calling `int 21h`. By writing `MOV AX,4CH` you will set `AL` with this value and not `AH`. In AL you can set exit code.

Either do (option 1):

```
mov ah,4CH
int 21h
```

or (option 2)

```
mov AX,4C00H ; or change 00 to any exit code you want.
int 21h
```

Comment: So after changing the code would the final value for:
AX = 4C04
BX = 0232

Comment: if you use option 1 - yes, In option 2 you overwrite the whole `AX`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I understand.

Comment: " By writing MOV AX,4CH you will set only AL" is not true. AH will be set to 0

Comment: @Tommylee2k yup, I wanted to say that `AL` will get this value of `4C` and not `AH`. I've updated to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "In AL you can set exit code."?
Is exit to DOS and exit code different?

Comment: exit to DOS is just end your program and return control to DOS, but you can, in `AL` return different status code of your program so the caller might do something based on this value. `0` usually indicates that everything when ok, `1` - could be one type of error, `2` - another and so on. So if your application is called from a a BAT script, this status (sometimes called error level) could be use to control if next actions should be executed or the script execution should stop.